# Using ant to access a third property when concatenating 2 existing ones?

Tags: ant, properties, el

So I have something like code below

```
<target name="testIt">
    <property name="appname" value="ApplicationOne"/>
    <property name="ApplicationOne-serveraddress" value="http://ApplicationOne.com"></property>
    <property name="ApplicationTwo-serveraddress" value="http://ApplicationTwo.com"></property>
    <echo message="${${appname}-serveraddress}"></echo>
</target>
```

Is there a way to do it? obviously, this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post about using antlib props in ant helped me](http://wdarby.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-antlib-props-in-ant-18.html) with  [Nesting of Braces](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) basically you have to download the jar and include

```
<project xmlns:props="antlib:org.apache.ant.props">
  <typedef uri="antlib:org.apache.ant.props"
    resource="org/apache/ant/props/antlib.xml"
    classpath="ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar"/>      
 <propertyhelper>
  <props:nested />
</propertyhelper>
```

Dont forget the xmlns. I downloaded the jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ant-props/ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a property with values from others. Is that what you are looking for?

```
<target name="testit">
    <property name="a" value="a"/>
    <property name="b" value="b"/>
    <property name="aandb" value="${a}{b}"/>
    <echo message="hello ${aandb}"/>
</target>
```

new ant support a way to make property local.

```
<target name="testit">
    <property name="a" value="a"/>
    <property name="b" value="b"/>
    <local name="aandb" />
    <property name="aandb" value="${a}{b}"/>
    <echo message="hello ${aandb}"/>
</target>
```

This helps to avoid case where immutable properties causes trouble.

Comment: @ toskan : where is it? You have unaccepted the answer. It helps if post your solution and the answer you think more correct than the current one

Comment: i made a better example of what I wanted to actually do. The answer I can give as well